# ionic externalRootDirectory fails to write to SD card

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, filesystems

I have been trying without success to write to the (removable) SD card on Android devices using the "cordova-plugin-file" plugin in IONIC.

The documentation specifies the

```
externalRootDirectory
```

as "Android: the external storage (SD card) root."

However, when I write to this directory:

```
this.file.resolveDirectoryUrl( this.file.externalRootDirectory)
.then( (data)=>{
  result += "\n" + "resolveDirectoryUrl";
  newBasePath = data.nativeURL;
  this.file.createDir(newBasePath, newDirName, true)
  .then( ()=>{
    result += "\n" + "createDir";
    this.file.createFile(newBasePath, newFilePath, true)
    .then( ()=>{
      result += "\n" + "createFile";
      this.file.writeFile(newBasePath, newFilePath, this.thisRouteFile,  {append:true})
      .then( () => {
        result += "\n" + "writeFile OK";
      });
    });
  });
});
```

the file always gets written to internal memory, or an emulation, not the removable SD card.

There is much discussion of the problem, some citing

```
  <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

but I have found no resolution.

Is it possible to write to a removable SD card?

Comment: Please tell which directory path is used now. Also tell which path is used for SD card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: Use the [getExternalSdCardDetails()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails) function from [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails).

The "external directories" returned by `cordova-plugin-file` correspond to non-removable (internal) storage. 
This is because these emulated locations are guaranteed to always exist on all Android devices, whereas external/removable SD card locations are not supported by all hardware vendors, are manufacturer- / Android-version-specific, and may not exist if an external SD card is not inserted into the reader.

For example, on a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 7.1.1:

- `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` returns `file:///storage/emulated/0/`
- `cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory` returns `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/cordova.plugins.diagnostic.example/`

which are filepaths on non-removable internal storage.

By contrast, the [getExternalSdCardDetails()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails) function from [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails) returns the location and details of removable external SD cards.

For example, on a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 7.1.1 it returns:

```
[{
    "path": "/storage/4975-1401/Android/data/cordova.plugins.diagnostic.example/files",
    "filePath": "file:///storage/4975-1401/Android/data/cordova.plugins.diagnostic.example/files",
    "canWrite": true,
    "freeSpace": 16254009344,
    "type": "application"
}, {
    "path": "/storage/4975-1401",
    "filePath": "file:///storage/4975-1401",
    "canWrite": false,
    "freeSpace": 16254009344,
    "type": "root"
}]
```

which are filepaths on external removable storage.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may miss the permissions to access to the external storage.

The cordova-plugin-file plugin adds lines to AndroidManifest.xml to request the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions but this in not enough anymore with the new Android permissions checking mechanism.

Starting with Android 6, you have to request permissions at run time instead of just having to put it in the manifest.

This means that each time you call a function that requires special permission, you have to ensure you have the permission by calling Android functions.

You can use the [Android-permissions plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/) to request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission at run time.