# Phonegap cordova create directory on micro SD

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I'm developing an app on android using phonegap/cordova.

I'm trying to create a directory on my micro SD with the following code:

```
function createMicroSdDir(){
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,
function fileEntryCallback(fileEntry) {
fileEntry.getDirectory("myDirectory", { create: true, exclusive: false });
}
);
}
```

but the directory is created on internal memory.

Any ideas? Tks in advance

Comment: `externalRootDirectory` is the emulated storage, which is the internal memory. It is quite hard to manipulate micro SD files even with native Android.You have to use Storage Access Framework for that. But it is for native Android. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that with cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Write file example:

```js
var fileName = 'myfile.txt';
var data = '...';
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function( directoryEntry ) {
    directoryEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true }, function( fileEntry ) {
        fileEntry.createWriter( function( fileWriter ) {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = function( result ) {
                console.log( 'done.' );
            };
            fileWriter.onerror = function( error ) {
                console.log( error );
            };
            fileWriter.write( data );
        }, 
  function( error ) { console.log( error ); } );
    }, 
 function( error ) { console.log( error ); } );
},
 function( error ) { console.log( error ); } );
```

Comment: Tks, but again the file is created on internal memory.

Comment: @npm make sure your Manifest.xml has the write external storage permission.

Comment: And please read all post here: [storage](http://rickluna.com/wp/2014/01/accessing-external-storage-in-android-phonegap-3-3/)

Answer (score 0):

`cordova-plugin-file` does not support referencing removable micro-SD card location(s) on Android. Only internal emulated "SD card" locations are supported.

However, you can use the [getExternalSdCardDetails()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails) function from [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to obtain the location and details of removable external SD cards.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47021861/777265) for more details.

Comment: function listSD(){
    alert("NPM1");
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails(function(details){
     alert("NPM2");
     details.forEach(function(detail){
      alert("detail.freeSpace = [" + detail.freeSpace + "]");
      alert("detail.filePath = [" + detail.filePath + "]");
      if(detail.canWrite && details.freeSpace > 100000){
       cordova.file.externalSdCardDirectory = detail.filePath;
       // Then: write file to external SD card
      }
     });
    }, function(error){
     alert(error);
    });
   }

Comment: can u plz add an example on how to create a dir after getting the sd card path from the diag-plugin ?